# Java Socket Programming. Getting error at the server side

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, client-server

I have written a java socket programming in which two strings are to be given to the server from the client side. The server will return the concatenated string and the length of the concatenated string.
The target is to send "exit" string to the server to close the connection after getting the desired result. I am getting the desired result (server is sending the concatenated string and size) but I am getting error in server side.

I am also getting four copies of my inputted strings at server side instead of getting one copy.
Here is the output screenshot
[image]

Here is my server side code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class Provider1{

           ServerSocket providerSocket;
           Socket connection = null;
           ObjectOutputStream out;
           ObjectInputStream in;
           String message;
           String x="";
           int count=0;
           Provider1(){}
           void run()
           {
                try{
                //1. creating a server socket
                providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
                //2. Wait for connection
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
                connection = providerSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                //3. get Input and Output streams
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();
                in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                sendMessage("Connection successful");
              //4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
               do{
                      try{
                          message="";
                          message = (String)in.readObject();
                          System.out.println("client>" + message);
                          x+=message;
                          count++;
                          if(count==2)
                          {
                              sendMessage("The concatenated string : "+x);
                              sendMessage("The length of concatenated string : "+x.length());
                              message="exit";
                           }
                           if (message.equals("exit"))
                               sendMessage(message);
                       }
                       catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                             System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                       }
              }while(!message.equals("exit"));
         }
         catch(IOException ioException){
               ioException.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally{
             //4: Closing connection
              try{
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    providerSocket.close();
                 }
                 catch(IOException ioException){
                      ioException.printStackTrace();
                 }
           }
     }
         void sendMessage(String msg)
         {
             try{
                out.writeObject(msg);
                out.flush();
              }
              catch(IOException ioException){
                   ioException.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          public static void main(String args[])
          {
                Provider1 server = new Provider1();
                while(true)
                {
                     server.run();
                }
           }
   }
```

This is my client side code

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class Requester1{
Socket requestSocket;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;
Requester1(){}
void run()
{
    try{
        //1. creating a socket to connect to the server
        requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2004);
        System.out.println("Connected to localhost in port 2004");
        //2. get Input and Output streams
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
        //3: Communicating with the server
        do{
            try{
                message = (String)in.readObject();
                System.out.println("server>" + message);
                sendMessage("Hello");
                sendMessage("There");
                message = "exit";
                sendMessage(message);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException classNot){
                System.err.println("data received in unknown format");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("exit"));
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost){
        System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        //4: Closing connection
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            requestSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        //System.out.println("client>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Requester1 client = new Requester1();
    client.run();
}
    }
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your exception is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 1):

Your read loop continues until `"bye"` is read, and the client closed the socket without sending it. So this is what happens.

You merely need to make your reading code more robust by explicitly catching `EOFException`, and terminating the read loop when you getting it.

Your client also needs to read the messages that are being sent to it. Otherwise you will provoke a connection reset.

Comment: @Piotr If that's a comment it should be addressed to the OP. If it's an answer it should be posted as an answer. If it's a comment on my answer it's redundant.

Comment: @Piotr There is no 'it wants to send a response but nobody is listening' section in my answer. Those are your words. It is a section *in your comment*. So your comment is an extension of your comment? So it is your own comment that isn't clear? This isn't making any sense. And it doesn't have anything to do with the actual problem here.

Comment: Right, copy & pasted wrong fragment.

I wanted to paste this "client also needs to read the messages that are being sent to it." I think that it might be not clear for user3804152 what is the exact flow of the messages between client and server, and what does it mean that it needs to read message that are being sent (given that his/her code is in general low quality, I'm assuming that an extensive example is needed to explain to problem). Fell free to downvote my comment, if you think that this is necessary :-)

Comment: @Piotr 'What does it mean to read' is not a question that needs an answer. He is already reading messages in his existing code.